# How to find a wrong character in my grammar

Tags: c#, parsing, gold-parser

I started working on the gold parser and tried to adopt its syntax to [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23). This is a fragment code. I'm interested in what this particular part does, and if I can see which of the characters in the text which i entered with textbox is wrong with my grammar?

```
private void TokenErrorEvent(LALRParser parser, TokenErrorEventArgs args)
{
    string message = "Token error with input: '"+args.Token.ToString()+"'";

}

private void ParseErrorEvent(LALRParser parser, ParseErrorEventArgs args)
{
    string message = "Parse error caused by token: '"+args.UnexpectedToken.ToString()+"'";

}
```

Comment: @close voters: off topic, granted, if we are strict about mcve. but unclear? interfacing with complex systems like parsers often it is not immedlately obvious even with documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gold parser uses events to communicate with the host application. You posted handlers for two of them, which are:

- OnTokenError... unrecognizable input. cannot do anything about this except fixing the source.
- OnParseError... encountered a token it cannot parse. You can decide how to proceed with the `ContinueMode`: supply a replacement token, ignore, or stop.

According to [documentation](http://www.goldparser.org/engine/1/net/van-loenhout/doc/com.calitha.goldparser.LocationMembers.html), source location information is available with these properties:

```
args.UnexpectedToken.Location.LineNr
```

and

```
args.UnexpectedToken.Location.ColumnNr
```

They are both zero-based, so if you split your source into an array of lines, you can directly use `LineNr` as index, and then the `SubString` function to point to the first character of the unexpected token literal.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am new in this and trying to understand.I wrote a grammar and  what i'm trying to do is to display that  character that was entered incorrectly . Is it possible to set any pointer to textbox to find out which symbol is not correct? Sorry if my question is not formed correctly

Comment: if "any pointer to textbox" means the caret, use LineNr and ColumnNr to position it. how this is done, depends on the frontend (wpf? winforms?)

Comment: Thanks, I understand.Yes, I'm using winforms.